# Memory leak warnings in swiftui over Image

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, memory-leaks

So i'm making a photo editor app and I'm getting leak warnings in Xcode and in instruments. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or if anything wrong at all. I replicated the errors down below.

```
@MainActor
class Model: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var photosPickerItem: PhotosPickerItem? {
        didSet{
            Task{
                guard let photosPickerItem = photosPickerItem else {
                    return
                }
                try await loadTransferrable(from: photosPickerItem)
            }
        }
    }
    @Published var imageData: Data?
    
    func loadTransferrable(from item: PhotosPickerItem) async throws{
        if (item.supportedContentTypes.contains(UTType.image)) || (item.supportedContentTypes.contains(UTType.jpeg)) ||
            (item.supportedContentTypes.contains(UTType.png)) ||
            (item.supportedContentTypes.contains(UTType.webP)) ||
            (item.supportedContentTypes.contains(UTType.tiff)){
            if let data = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self){
                imageData = data
            }
        }
    }
    
    func clearImage(){
        imageData = nil
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingPicker = false
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if model.imageData != nil{
                let uiimage = UIImage(data: model.imageData!)
                Image(uiImage: uiimage!).resizable().scaledToFit()
            }
            HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    isShowingPicker.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Picker Button")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    model.clearImage()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Clear Button")
                })
            }
        }.photosPicker(isPresented: $isShowingPicker, selection: $model.photosPickerItem)
    }
}
```

[errors i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StzGV.png)
I'm getting these errors after I clear the imageData and set it back to nil.

If this is actually a memory leak I'd like to deal with it somehow but I have no idea. Anyway thanks for the help :)

Comment: Your code works very well for me (no errors, no problems), on MacOS 13.3, using Xcode 14.3 beta, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
It could be different on older systems. What system are you on?

Comment: I'm using macOS 12.6.1 and Xcode 14.2 and yea I tested with a simulator and my phone. Did you check the memory graph?

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, rather than `Task` you would use the modifier `.task(id: model.photosPickerItem)` to start your async work. That way it will be automatically cancelled and restarted when the id param changes.

Also, your reference type that has the func for the background work would not normally be `@MainActor` because then the async func will run on the main thread. So you might as-well have not bothered with the reference type at all.

That being said, the memory leak is probably `UIImage` init since we aren't supposed to init objects inside the View init or body.

Comment: Hey! I'm using `@MainActor` bc when I don't have it I get an error stating "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates." I added a UIImage var to my class and init it in `.onAppear` and `.task` and I was still getting the leak.

Comment: You can fix that error with `Task { @MainActor in imageData = data `